# How to get live camera preview in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to create an application in Windows phone8. In this application i want to show live camera preview with different effect in multiple frame using C# in Windows phone 8. please give me a solution

Answer (score 1):

To use the camera in Windows phone 8 you need to use the `PhotoCamera` object.  Best to create this object on your `OnNavigatedTo` like so:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo (System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.Primary) == true) 
    { 
        cam = new PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary); 
        cam.CaptureImageAvailable += new EventHandler<Microsoft.Devices.ContentReadyEventArgs>(cam_CaptureImageAvailable); 
        viewfinderBrush.SetSource(cam); 
    }
    else 
    {
        txtMessage.Text = "A Camera is not available on this device."; }
    }   
}
// dispose when we leave
protected override void OnNavigatingFrom (System.Windows.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (cam != null) 
    { 
        cam.Dispose(); 
    } 
}
```

To actually capture the image from the camera you can then call the ***CaptureImage*** method on the cam object.